# Which technique should I use to encrypt/decrypt data in MS Access database file?

Tags: c#, ms-access, encryption

I am working on final project for my C# class. My project is a password management program. As I first thought to use just encrypting/decrypting file in AES but my professor pointed out that MS Access database would be much better choice.

My question is: how would I encrypt data in database using code I already have?  So day I am referring to this article ( gutgames.com/post/AES-Encryption-in-C.aspx ) which works perfect and I can encrypt/decrypt data. Should I use thus code to encrypt ms access file? please post some useful links how would I encrypt my data.

Comment: Your professor probably wants you to use the [native encryption provided with Access.](http://databases.about.com/od/productinfo/a/encryption.htm)  You might want to clarify this with him.

Comment: @Robert Harvey♦: this sounds perfect. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypting the Access file itself would limit your options regarding concurrent access and people being able to access different bits of the database.  Your end goal should be to encrypt data /within/ the database, and ensure people can only access what they should be allowed to access.  One of the common ways of securely managing passwords is to hash/encrypt the password and store that (for which the code you linked to would be fine).  Upon login to whatever system the database is storing the passwords for, you would hash/encrypt the provided password and compare it to the stored one.  If the user needs a new password, generate a new one, store the hashed/encrypted copy, and give the user their new password.

If you want to be able to recover the password (i.e. if you want a Forgot My Password function to give the user their password rather than give them a new one) encrypt it, so that's it's decryptable to provide back to the user.  If you're okay with just issuing new passwords, hash it.

Comment: As long as we're talking best practices here, storing passwords is bad practice, encrypted or not.

Comment: @Robert Harvey♦: thanks for your note. I wasn't panning to have such option anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not sure I follow.  If you don't store the password, how do you check if the password someone has entered is correct?

Comment: You store a hash of the password.  When the user enters their password, you hash it, and compare it to the stored hash.

Comment: That's what I said to do.  I thought you were saying not to store them at all, regardless of the obfuscation.  Never mind.

Comment: Hashing is different from encryption. But for a password management program hashing is not an option.I would advise some scheme where the database file is also protected against changes (e.g. using a MAC, HMAC or AEX). It is also better to have some mechanism to check the master password, which is decoupled from the decoding of the file itself. Personally, I would also opt for an application where each password is decrypted only when needed and destroyed from some kind of secure memory location (that isn't swapped to disk). Of course, this would not be homework anymore :)