# Reading AES encrypted access database file using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm encrypting database file for security with C# when the application uses the database its decrypts it. During data manipulation the database file in decrypted mode and data can be modified. So i want that my C# application read db file in encrpted mode. Is it possible? or any other solution that only my application can run the db file?

Comment: No it is not possible. At least using the standard providers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which technique should I use to encrypt/decrypt data in MS Access database file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236289/which-technique-should-i-use-to-encrypt-decrypt-data-in-ms-access-database-file)